# LinQtoXpo and sqlexpress

Tags: devexpress, xpo

How can I access  sqlepxress database using linQPad I need to use the LinqToXPO driver?

if the database was created from the EF model in VS2010, 
(you guys know how devexpress documentation is...none or litte) 
thanks.

Comment: What is exactly missing in [DevEx documentation](http://search.devexpress.com/?q=linqpad+&p=T4%7cP2%7c0&d=208) regarding your problem?

Comment: got no dev exp dlls yet. trying to learn some of this XPO driver.

Comment: while on the same subject...>>The DevExpress.Xpo and DevExpress.Data assemblies that were used to compile the persistent classes assembly must be present in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). You will also need the DevExpress.Xpo.Linq assembly for XPO versions prior to v2011 vol 2. If these assemblies are not available in GAC, you can simply place them next to the persistent classes assembly. << any links on how to do this task ? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you have created XPO-objects for the tables you want to access in LinqPad, this post will walk you trough the process: http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/xpo/archive/2011/12/27/xpo-s-new-friend-is-the-linqpad.aspx.

It won't matter if the database is created manually, by XPO or EF (code first).

Please let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: thanks Fredrik,that tip helps... if I have a single class on the database lets say created with EF, and have two properties code,description and they are strings, the LinqtoXPO to get an xpQuery or xpcollection cannot be run on LinqPad til I have a XPO DLL , correct ?

Comment: That's correct. Not in LinqPad, since it needs a reference to the assembly containing your class.

Comment: Is there anything else you would like to know about using LinqPad with XPO, or can you set the answer as accepted?

Comment: apologize for it Fredrik, I increased the number but not mark it as accepted , thanks for the reminder.